# Constructing Binary Trees, Given Parent/Children

Tags: java, tree, linked-list

I'm attempting to construct a binary tree, where I'll be given the parent and left/right child of every node. I understand how to traverse a tree, but I'm not sure how to go about constructing it in the first place using my given information.

I'm mostly unsure of how to assemble the nodes while maintaining their relations to each other, I feel like Linked Lists could be what I need to implement, but I am shaky on my understanding of them.

Any clarification or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you need is an article or a tutorial on linked lists.  Search the web.  This isn't the kind of question people normally answer here.

Comment: How is the tree given to you?

Comment: We need more details to be able to help.

Comment: I am a bit confused by what do you mean by constructing  If there are list of nodes of the tree that already have a parent/child relationship. All you need to do is to find the root node (Node w/o parent) and that will bring you the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to make each node hold a reference to its parent node and left and right children. Like this:

```
class Node{
    private Node parent;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

This way you'll be able to couple together a bunch of nodes which will be more like a bidirectional graph (i.e. you can start traversing it from any node you want).

You can also create a `Tree` class to manage nodes.

```
class Tree{
    private Node root;

    public Tree(Node root){
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void addLeftChild(Node parent, Node leftChild){
        leftChild.parent = parent;
        parent.left = leftChild
    }

    //methods to traverse tree and so on...
}
```

Note that this is a very trivial example of what can be done, which won't actually compile, but it may point you towards making your own tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's going to be a complete binary tree, then the most efficient way to do it would probably be with an array implementation; however, it's not good for a non-complete binary tree.  In that case a simple approach is to define a `BinaryNode` as follows:

```
public BinaryNode(BinaryNode parent, BinaryNode leftChild, 
                  BinaryNode rightChild, Object data) 
{
    this.parent = parent;
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
    this.data = data;
}
```

If you know there will only be one overarching data type for a given instantiation of a tree, then you can change the above definition to a generics based one.  If not, `data` being an `Object` will have to do.

If necessary, you can create a `BinaryTree` class which could store the root of your tree, but note the every `BinaryNode` is a "`BinaryTree`".

The key insight here is that the `BinaryNode` object is enough in itself to entirely store the tree structure.  Of course, you need to implement `addNode()`, `removeNode()`, etc, but this simple structure defines the relationships that we want, and leads to intuitive, recursive method definitions.

Depending on what types of operations that you'll need to perform, there's a good chance that you don't actually need to store the `parent` attribute in your `node`.